# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null onReadyStateChangeReplacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm building a Rails app with Angular built in.

Everything's working just fine, but I've notice a strange error when I first land on one of my Angular-heavy pages after following a link. The Angular does not run -- the handlebars are visible despite ng_cloaks, etc -- and in the console I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null 
  onReadyStateChangeReplacement
```

**If I refresh, the page works fine!** *Also if I just enter the url instead of following the link to that URL, it works fine*. So maybe this is a link/Turbolinks thing?

It's Rails 4. I'm adapting a pattern of Angular integration described [here](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/).

And I threw these lines into my application.coffee file (first in-app JS loaded) on advice to counteract Ng/Turbolinks not playing well together:

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  $('[ng-app]').each ->
    module = $(this).attr('ng-app')
    angular.bootstrap(this, [module])
```

Any ideas what this might be? / What to look into?

Thanks

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? Ran into same issue

Comment: Can you show one of the links causing this?

Comment: the error is in your angular. please include your controller and the ng directives of your DOM. the answer is probably there

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this happening to me when using MiniProfiler gem. There's a fix for the issue but it's not merged yet to master https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/pull/13